# Elbow method for tuning DBSCAN when minPts=1

Tags: machine-learning, cluster-analysis, nearest-neighbor, hyperparameters, dbscan

The elbow method calls for setting `k=MinPts`, but what do you do when `MinPts=1`? Is the elbow method still usable in this situation, and if so, how do you determine `k`?

I tried the elbow method with `k=1`, which results in all the distances equalling zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the elbow method for dbscan you set k/minPts, which will help you choose a good value for eps. The original DBSCAN paper suggests setting minPts to the dimensionality of the data plus one or higher. So MinPts < 3 makes typically not much sense.

This is from the [man page](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/dbscan/versions/1.1-11/topics/dbscan) of dbscan() in the R package `dbscan`. But this is similar to any other implementation:

> Setting parameters for DBSCAN
>
> The parameters `minPts` and `eps` depend on each other and
> changing one typically requires changing the other one as well.
> The original DBSCAN paper suggests to start by setting `minPts` to
> the dimensionality of the data plus one or higher. `minPts`
> defines the minimum density around a core point (i.e., the minimum
> density for non-noise areas). Increase the parameter to suppress
> more noise in the data and require more points to form a cluster.
> A suitable neighborhood size parameter `eps` given a fixed value
> for `minPts` can be found visually by inspecting the
> `kNNdistplot()` of the data using `k = minPts - 1` (`minPts`
> includes the point itself, while the k-nearest neighbor distance
> does not). The k-nearest neighbor distance plot sorts all data
> points by their k-nearest neighbor distance. A sudden increase of
> the kNN distance (a knee) indicates that the points to the right
> are most likely outliers. Choose `eps` for DBSCAN where the knee
> is.

Comment: Thanks for the reference. What would you suggest doing if the dimensionality of the data is not available? In Python, Scikit-Learn's implementation of DBSCAN allows for a precomputed distance matrix, in which case the dimensionality of the underlying data could conceivably be unknown. That is, unless there is some way to back into the number of dimensions from the distance matrix, but that is an entirely separate question.

Comment: One option is to estimate the intrinsic dimensionally of the data by applying MDS and see how many dimensions you need. You can then use the k-nearest neighbor distance plot on the MDS space to find a good eps. The other option is to experiment with minPrs and eps till you find a useful clustering.

Comment: MDS is non-linear, or manifold, - for visualization purposes suitable OK, not for further analysis. PCA's principle components, explaining the variance (but still in generalized mode) - can still be used in further calculations. I would only use MDS for possible outliers detection (or with IsolationTree) for further elimination of such samples

Comment: *elbow method* is OK to choose epsilon (or degree of contamination) -- but again under the assumptio of Normality of distribution (or linearity of dependency)